# In Bootstrap change the dropdown width dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

consider , ui consist more than 10 li elements were first four li elements should placed in first column next four to next column from left and so on..
dropdown width is increased according to li elements..
but there is no fixed width for dropdowns..

**(Dropdown down width change according to li elements)**

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to implement a dropdown with multiple columns similar to the one that can be found here http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/ which renders as follows [image: Multi column drop down]

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">One Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
    min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
    min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
    list-style: none;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333;
    white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        min-width: 240px !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```